# Is it possible to perform an OCR in certain area in a PDF with python?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to perform an OCR in certain area in a PDF with python? I am trying to build a program to extract some information from every PDF sheet like what Autodesk BIM360 do

Comment: The answer to "Is it possible to..." is yes as long as it's not self-inconsistent. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer**: I am the author of `borb` (the library used in this answer)

`borb` is an open-source, pure Python PDF library that plays nice with other famous libraries. e.g. you can insert `PIL` images, or `matplotlib` charts, and you can use `pytesseract` to apply OCR to your document.

There is a large examples repository in case you want to learn more. You can find a working example of OCR [there](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#72-performing-ocr-on-a-pdf) as well.

I'll repeat the example here for completeness:

```py
#!chapter_007/src/snippet_005.py
def main():

    # set up everything for OCR
    tesseract_data_dir: Path = Path("/home/joris/Downloads/tessdata-master/")
    assert tesseract_data_dir.exists()
    l: OCRAsOptionalContentGroup = OCRAsOptionalContentGroup(tesseract_data_dir)

    # read Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output_001.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])

    assert doc is not None

    # store Document
    with open("output_002.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What's happening here is that the OCR process is dumping its results in an invisible layer of the PDF (these are called optional content groups). Hence the name `OCRAsOptionalContentGroup`.

Afterwards, you can store the `Document` again, and it will appear to contain text, you`ll be able to search it, select the text, and everything you`re used to.